# Get surrounding DOM node of selection

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I need to get the surrounding DOM node from a selected text. How do I do that with the Firefox Add-on SDK? 
Or is there any other possibility that I can use in my extension?

E.g. (the selected is uppercase)
`<b class='foo'>here is SELected text</b>`

Aim is to get the class-name.

Comment: https://getfirebug.com/?  right click, inspect element?

Comment: @Rob A : "example?"
the feasibility and way how to get the surrounding DOMNode is much more important than some proper extension for the example.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstanding that you want. You can declared a click function for each element in the DOM and the callback display the className of the clicked element for example.

Answer (score 1):

A content script will have access to the [`window.getSelection()` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Selection). Theoretically, a selection can consist out of several distinct ranges. I have never seen a multi-range selection however and you probably want to assume that only the first range is relevant. A range has a [`commonAncestorContainer` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/range.commonAncestorContainer) that allows you getting the element containing all the selected text parts. Meaning that you need to do something like this in a content script:

```js
var selection = window.getSelection();
if (selection.rangeCount >= 1)
{
  var range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
  alert(range.commonAncestorContainer.className);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A selection doesn't necessarily have a single parent node.  The endpoints of a selection range can be in different nodes, with any number of nodes included within the range, and a selection can consist of multiple ranges. A `selection` object is actually quite complicated.